# What is error 3007?

Tags: diablo-iii

I have been thrown out of my game and shortly after error 3007 appears and I have to reconnect in order to continue.

In solo this is beyond annoying because I have to restart whatever I was doing, in multiplayer I can rejoin, sometimes fast enough that my partner doesn't know I've left.

I saw Bashiok's post on the forums that basically said it was on the player's end, but didn't describe what or how to mitigate it.

What is error 3007 and how to I nerf it?

Comment: I wonder if it's related to your MTU size, something Blizzard has suffered with before in their network code

Comment: @ChrisS At least that would be something legit to work with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I don't know the exact cause of the error, I stumbled on something that seemed to work. Initially I was getting booted every 5 minutes or so with the 3007 error, but if I joined the general chat (clicking the gear in the top left of the chat panel, expanding Join Channel and then clicking General) I was able to play for hours with no problems at all.

It's not really a solution so much as a work around, but after a number of tries where I wouldn't join and would be kicked, followed by joining and always being able to play for hours, it certainly worked for me.

Comment: This has, strangely, worked, tonight...

Comment: This is continuing to work for me, so I'm going to mark it accepted, but man would I love to know what the issue is so I can kill [General] :-)

Comment: I wish I had more information about the actual error, as I'm a little tired of the spammers and trolls in General myself, but I'm still getting booted whenever I forget to join. Hopefully it gets fixed soon.

Answer (score 7):

The solutions to error 3007 seem to be many and varied, based on a cursory inspection of Blizzards support forums. Your best bet will be to post there or otherwise contact customer support to troubleshoot this one.

[Bashlok Sez:](http://d3db.com/blue/thread/5149146693/us)

> Error 3007 is unlikely related to any game service issues, and is something we'll need to troubleshoot with individuals experiencing it. For that reason I recommend visiting the technical support forum, where there have been a number of threads and replies where our customer services representatives are attempting to help people resolve them.
>
> http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/5386227/

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what exactly 3007 is the error code for other than client disconnect, but Blizzard's Diablo 3 connection debugging guide is available [here](http://us.battle.net/support/en/article/diablo-iii-connection-troubleshooting).  Blizzard's Twitter account was touting that as an answer to disconnection issues.

Another reference I found that was specific for error 3007 is [this article](http://www.examiner.com/article/diablo-3-error-3007-troubleshooting), however I'm not sure whether or not that successfully fixes the issue for most players or not.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:  I still have this error and I working around it by joining the general chat (click blueish General text in chat and enter message after logging on, but before starting game). When I join I don't get disconnected for the 3007 error - weird I know.

I found this [link](http://us.battle.net/support/en/article/error-3007) to Battle.net with a list of solutions they have.  Sounds like a blizzard server problem being to sensitive to player drops (maybe too many players for server).

I would only try the router and security software for short periods as this leaves your computer exposed to malicious attacks.

[Here](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/5149007206) are some additional options: router firmware upgrade, port forwarding

Answer (score 0):

It is an annoying problem indeed, that hits many players. Blizzard's trying to say that it is not a server problem but I would say that probably they are still investigating how to solve it.

There are too many users afflicted and **the facts are that there are periods where you can play for hours** without any error 3007, usually in low-traffic times (e.g. in Europe morning/first afternoon/late night) **and periods instead that you get this error each 5/10 minutes**.

**Joining General** chat channel could help but it is not always enough. I found that it is even more helpful writing a message to the chat with high frequency (every 2 minutes). I don't like spamming random things in General chat so I tried sending them to **Party chat** (playing solo) and it seems working the same.

We are in the field of "magic" here, but hopefully it could help you.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem and I solved it by disconnecting my D-link 615 router, instead plugging my internet straight into the PC.

Comment: So everybody should bypass their routers? I think not! :P